# Manipulating objects in a for loop - Angular

Tags: angular

So I am getting a array of objects from a REST endpoint and adding them to a table which is working fine. I want to run toLocaleDateStrring() on the date though before it adds it to the table so people can understand it.

Here is my table row

```
<tr *ngFor="let entry of entries">
      <td>{{ entry.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ entry.uuid }}</td>
      <td>{{ entry.reason }}</td>
      <td>{{ entry.created }}</td>
      <td>{{ entry.expires }}</td>
      <td>{{ entry.case }}</td>
    </tr>
```

but for created and expires for instance I would want do do something like `{{entry.created.toLocaleDateSrring()}}`

I am using angular 4

Comment: So... do it. What's the problem (other than the incorrectly spelt method name)? And why not use the date pipe instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that, but better would be to use a pipe

```
@Pipe({name: 'toLocalDateString'})
export class ToLocalDateStringPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val) {
    return /* convert value to local date string */
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
<tr *ngFor="let entry of entries">
  <td>{{ entry.name | toLocalDateString }}</td>
  <td>{{ entry.uuid | toLocalDateString}}</td>
  <td>{{ entry.reason | toLocalDateString}}</td>
  <td>{{ entry.created | toLocalDateString}}</td>
  <td>{{ entry.expires | toLocalDateString}}</td>
  <td>{{ entry.case | toLocalDateString}}</td>
</tr>
```

There is also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html